# Getting data from DB set it on Array and display on a Table

Tags: java, arrays, derby, windowbuilder, eclipse-oxygen

That's what I need to do so I'll explain more. Things I've done:

- I've made connection.
- I've inserted data on table successfully.
- I can print exceptions on my GUI (I'm sending data from the GUI).

This is my code:

```
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    public class getInfoDBemp {
   private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:derby:EvCo-RegHuella;";
   Connection conn; 
   public getInfoDBemp () {     
   try {            
        this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL);
        if (this.conn != null) {                
            try {                   
                PreparedStatement ps = this.conn.prepareStatement(main.statementEmpreg);
                ps.execute();
                while (ps.getMoreResults()) {
                    String testprint = ps.getResultSet().toString();
                    System.out.println(testprint);
                                        }
                ps.close();                 
                    }catch(SQLException ex){
                    String exString = ex.toString();
                    System.out.println("ERROR " + exString);
                }
        }
    }catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.print(e);
        }   
}
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to get the data from my DB. It doesn't cause any exception but it does not print any data or exception. I know I'm doing it wrong but I don't know how or why. Can you give me a hand?

**EXTRA INFO:**

- I'm using Eclipse Oxygen.
- I'm using Derby Database JDCB.
- I'm using Windowbuilder.
- I know Java Programming.
- I'm an "Advanced Newbie"
- I'm very bad at writing in English but I can understand perfectly.

**NEW EDITED INFO**

This is the code now:

```
    public getInfoDBemp () {        
try {           
        this.conn = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL);
        if (this.conn != null) {                
            try {   
                Statement st = this.conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(main.statementEmpreg);
                while (rs.next()){
                    int ID_r = rs.getInt("ID");
                    String Nombre_r = rs.getString("Nombre");
                    System.out.println(ID_r+" "+Nombre_r);                  
                    }
                st.close();
```

Im gettin the information printed perfectly on my Console, but the point its to print it on a table row by row on windowbuilder @ eclipse.

Comment: One does not code everything in the constructor. I suggest you do basic Java programming before you jump into this complex problem.

Comment: Test the query in `main.statementEmpreg` directly in DB and see if returns any row.

Comment: Well i've made it work! im getting the information printed at console, now the final step its to print the information on a table on windowbuilder